# Namespace Circular Reference in R

Tags: r, namespaces

Help, I'm being tortured by R. When I try to load a custom package called RedTor. It generates

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RedTor’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.7 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required

I checked the obvious.  I have version 0.4.10 of rlang installed.  This isn't just related to RedTor. library(dplyr) generates the same error.  It's more pervasive and seems to be a namespace problem. If I use the unloadNamespace() function

> unloadNamespace("rlang")

I get

> Error in unloadNamespace("rlang") :
> namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘ellipsis’, ‘testthat’, ‘pkgload’, ‘pillar’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘htmltools’, > ‘usethis’ so cannot be unloaded

So I need to unload those, but those may in turn generate other messages.

It seems that this is related to what gets loaded in R. I run sessionInfo() and note what is loaded via a namespace (and not attached) - about 30-41 packages. Wish I knew how to keep these from loading. Any help appreciated. I have no .rdata being loaded as far as I can tell and no packages loading in .renviron.

Below is the result of sessionInfo() when I start R.  It shows version 0.4.7 of rlang being loaded even though I have 0.4.10 installed.  I'm pretty sure it's not just rlang and that rlang is just the first to throw the error.  This would occur because other packages are being loaded via a namespace that are "out of date".

> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
> LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] devtools_2.2.1 usethis_1.6.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.3.0          fansi_0.4.0       rprojroot_1.3-2   withr_2.2.0
> digest_0.6.23     crayon_1.3.4
> [8] assertthat_0.2.1  R6_2.4.1          backports_1.1.5   magrittr_1.5      rlang_0.4.7
> cli_2.0.2         remotes_2.1.1
> [15] rstudioapi_0.11   fs_1.4.1          testthat_2.3.2    callr_3.4.3       ellipsis_0.3.0
> desc_1.2.0        tools_3.6.3
> [22] glue_1.4.2        compiler_3.6.3    pkgload_1.0.2     processx_3.4.1    pkgbuild_1.0.8
> sessioninfo_1.1.1 memoise_1.1.0

Finally, I have even tried to run a script to unload all the namespaces

```
si <- sessionInfo()
loadednames <- names(si$loadedOnly)
ctr <- 1
n <- length(loadednames)
nold <- n + 1
while (n > 0 & n < nold) {
  cat(n, " ")
  for (i in n:1) {
    try(unloadNamespace(loadednames[i]), silent = TRUE)
  }
  si <- sessionInfo()
  loadednames <- names(si$loadedOnly)
  n <- length(loadednames)  
  ctr <- ctr + 1
  if ( ctr > 100) break
}
```

This does not unload all the namespaces. But it gets me down to about 20.  Here is a partial output of sessionInfo() after running the above.  rlang is still in the list:

> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.7       fansi_0.4.0       tools_3.6.3
> pkgbuild_1.0.8    sessioninfo_1.1.1
> [8] cli_2.0.2         withr_2.2.0       ellipsis_0.3.0    remotes_2.1.1     assertthat_0.2.1
> digest_0.6.23     crayon_1.3.4
> [15] processx_3.4.1    callr_3.4.3       fs_1.4.1          memoise_1.1.0     glue_1.4.2
> compiler_3.6.3    prettyunits_1.1.1

So now I just try to unload the remaing namespaces until I can finally load my RedTor package.  This is a tortuous process and a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an .Rprofile file that runs any code at startup to load packages? Are you using the base R GUI or are you using RStudio? How do you know which version of rlang you have installed if that's not the one that's loading? Do you have multiple library paths set up? What happens if you run `install.packages("rlang")`?

Comment: Often an `update.packages()` will do, ideally in combination with the most recent R version. And: where does the package you are trying come from?

Comment: Could you change your question title to something clearer and more specific/informative please?

Comment: MrFlick - I do have an .rprofile loading devtools. Removing that cleared up the problem.  install.packages("rlang") doesn't help because I have the most recent version.  I have 2 entries in .libPaths, one points to a Google drive with the idea being that co-worker and I can be using the same version of the packages and the other points to /Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library

Captain Hat - happy to change the title.  I seriously understand that better titles help others find help if they have a similar problem.  I just haven't got one yet - Does Namespace Circular Reference work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a require(devtools) statement in my .rprofile.  Removing that seems to have cleared it up.